# What is the proper way to get all child entities in Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

Say I have a one to many relationship between `City` and `Person`.

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "city")
data class City(
    @PrimaryKey
    val cityId: Int,
    val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val personId: Long = 0,
    val name: String,
    val cityId: Int
)
```

The goal is to get all person in the database and their corresponding city. According to the Jetpack documentation, the obvious way is to create a `CityWithPersons` class.

```
data class CityWithPersons(
    @Embedded
    val city: City,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "cityId", entityColumn = "cityId")
    val persons: List<Person>
)
```

Get all `CityWithPersons`, then combine persons from there.

But in my scenario, there could be less than 10 person and more than 1000 cities in the database. It seems ridiculous and very inefficient to do it this way.

Other potential approaches could be:

- get a full list of person then query the city with `cityId` one by one
- embed the `City` in `Person` entitiy instead of `cityId`
- Do it as many to many relationship. `PersonWithCity` will just have a `cities` array with one entity

I wonder which would be the best way to do it? Or a better way I didn't think of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder which would be the best way to do it? Or a better way I didn't think of?

I don't believe that the many-many relationship would provide any performance advantage as you would still need to search through one of the tables. Nor do I believe that *get a full list of person then query the city with cityId one by one* would be of benefit (however do you need to? (rhetorical) See the PersonAndCity that effectively does this in one go)

> the obvious way is to create a CityWithPersons class

Seeing that you are looking at the issue from the Person perspective, then why not PersonWithCity class?

> embed the City in Person entitiy instead of cityId :-

```
data class PersonWithCity(

    @Embedded
    val person: Person,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "cityId",entityColumn = "cityId")
    val city: City
)
```

And a Dao such as :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person")
fun getPersonWithCity(): List<PersonWithCity>
```

Do you need to build everything?

Another consideration I don't believe you've considered :-

```
data class PersonAndCity(

    val personId: Long,
    val name: String,
    val cityId: Int,
    val cityName: String,

)
```

And a Dao such as

```
@Query("SELECT *, city.name AS cityName FROM person JOIN city ON person.cityId = city.cityId")
fun getPersonAndCity(): List<PersonAndCity>
```

- No @Relation

Running the above 2 and the original with 100000 Person and 10000 cities (I assume more Person rows) and Person randomly linked to a City extracting all with each of the 3 methods then the results are :-

- 690ms (extracts 10000 Cities with ? Persons) using CityWithPersons
- 1560ms (extracts all 100000 Persons with the City) using PersonWithCity
- 1475ms (extracts all 100000 Persons with the City information rather than a City object)

Changing to 10 Persons with 1000 Cities then

- 49ms (CityWithPersons (10000 extracted))
- 2ms (PersonWithCity (10) extracted)
- 5ms (PersonAndCity (10 extracted))

As such, the *best way* is dependant upon the what you are doing. As can be seen the ratio between Cities and Persons is a factor that should be considered.

In short you should undertake testing :-

For the results above I used :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,MyDatabase::class.java,"Mydb")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
        val dao = db.getAllDao()
        val people = 10
        val cities = 1000
        for(i in 1..cities) {
            dao.insertCity(City(null,"City00" + i))
        }
        for(i in 1..people) {
            dao.insertPerson(Person(null,"Person" + i,(1..cities).random()))
        }
        val TAG = "CITYPERSONINFO"
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting Test 1 - Using CityWithPerson")
        val usingCityWithPerson = dao.getCityWithPerson()
        Log.d(TAG,"Done Test 1. Rows Extracted = " + usingCityWithPerson.size)
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting Test 2 - UsingPersonAndCity")
        val usingPersonWithCity = dao.getPersonWithCity()
        Log.d(TAG,"Done Test 2. Rows Extracted = " + usingPersonWithCity.size)
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting Test 3 - UsingPersonAndCity (no @Relation just JOIN)")
        val usingPersonAndCity = dao.getPersonAndCity()
        Log.d(TAG,"Done Test 3. Rows Extracted = " + usingPersonAndCity.size)

    }
}
```

- Note that I uninstall the App between runs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was distracted from this project until now. Thanks for the clearly explained answer!  Both `PersonWithCity` and `PersonAndCity` work.